# Collecting tweets from search api-change formart of the output

Tags: python, api, twitter-oauth

i am using following code to search for tweets about an event

```
import json
import tweepy
consumer_key = 
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="manchesterarena",  lang="en").items():
    print(tweet)
```

My output looks like:

Status(in_reply_to_user_id_str=None, coordinates=None, retweeted=False, in_reply_to_user_id=None, retweeted_status=Status(in_reply_to_user_id_str=None, coordinates=None, retweeted=False, in_reply_to_user_id=None, created_at=datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 29, 9, 29, 55), contributors=None, possibly_sensitive=False..............

How can i get the tweets as a dictionary or in json format?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `._json` property of the tweet object:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="manchesterarena",  lang="en").items():
    print(tweet._json)
```

You are also currently likely to run up against rate limits - if you initialise your API as:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

Tweepy will be able to more gracefully handle the rate limits.

Comment: I have used the above code suggested by you to append the output to text file and i have collected some tweets into a .txt file. Now i am trying to load each tweet using following code: 
    import json
    from json import loads

    with open("del.txt") as f:
        for each in f:
            print(json.loads(each['text']))

I get following error:
   print(json.loads(each['text']))
   TypeError: string indices must be integers

Can you suggest me a better way?

Comment: You're skipping a step - you can't access the `'text'` attribute before you've created the json object. Try `print(json.loads(each)['text'])`

Comment: Also if the answer helped you, you can mark it as "correct" and/or vote up by using the buttons on its left